# Error While Activating A New WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook

I m learning to develop plugin and I am getting error on activation saying

> The plugin generated 157 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems
>   with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing
>   this plugin.

I tried removing and making a new one but same error. here is my code (basic PHP comment to start a plugin, nothing fancy).

```
/*
Plugin Name: Awesomeness
Plugin URI: http://www.example.com/
Author URI: http://www.example.com/
Author: abc
Description: Just a fun plugin
*/
function fubs(){
    error.log("this is working");
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'fubs');
```

There is no white space before or ending on PHP code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The plugin generated X characters of unexpected output during activation (WordPress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074477/the-plugin-generated-x-characters-of-unexpected-output-during-activation-wordpr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`error` is an undefined constant in your PHP code. You try to mix JavaScript with PHP, so PHP prints an error message.

Solution: Use PHP code in PHP and JavaScript code in JavaScript.