# Error message - The plugin generated 1 characters of unexpected output during activation in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a plugin. I make a query on "register_activation_hook". When I activate the plugin the Query work perfectly, but I get an error

> The plugin generated 1 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

What is the issue? I don't get it.

Here is my code:

```
function customtaxorder_init() {
    global $wpdb;
    $init_query = $wpdb->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $wpdb->terms LIKE 'term_order'");
    if ($init_query == 0) { $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE $wpdb->terms ADD `term_order` INT( 4 ) NULL DEFAULT '0'"); }

    //  For Previous Users Product Images
    $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    $postSql = "SELECT DISTINCT post_id
                    FROM ".$prefix."postmeta As meta
                    Inner Join ".$prefix."posts As post
                    On post.ID = meta.post_id
                    Where post_type = 'wpcproduct' 
                    And post_status = 'publish'
                    And meta_key Like '%product_img%'";
    $postQry = mysql_query($postSql);
    while($postRow = mysql_fetch_array($postQry)){
        $post_id = $postRow['post_id'];
        $meta_key = "product_images";

        $sql = "Select post.*, meta.*
                        From ".$prefix."posts As post
                        Inner Join ".$prefix."postmeta As meta
                        On post.ID = meta.post_id
                        Where post_type = 'wpcproduct' 
                        And post_status = 'publish'
                        And meta_key Like '%product_img%'
                        And post_id = ".$post_id;
        $qry = mysql_query($sql);
        $prod_key = array();
        $prod_value = array();
        $a = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
            $product_img = $row['meta_key'];

            $product_img = preg_replace("([0-9]+)", "", $product_img);

            $response[$a] = $row['meta_key'];
            $response[$a] = $row['meta_value'];

            $data[$a][$product_img] = $response[$a];

            $a = $a + 1;
        }
                //print_r($data);
        $data_serialize = serialize($data);

        $insert_images = "Insert Into ".$prefix."postmeta(post_id,meta_key,meta_value) Value('$post_id','$meta_key','$data_serialize')";
        mysql_query($insert_images);
    }

    //  Delete All product_img1,product_img2,product_img3
    mysql_query("Delete From ".$prefix."postmeta Where meta_key IN ('product_img1','product_img2','product_img3')");

    //  Update All product_price to Product Price
    $support_sql = "Select * From ".$prefix."postmeta Where meta_key Like '%product_price%'";
    $support_qry = mysql_query($support_sql);
    while($support_arr = mysql_fetch_array($support_qry)){
        $supportMetaID = $support_arr['post_id'];
        $supportMetaPrice = $support_arr['meta_key'];

        $price_split = explode("_", $supportMetaPrice);

        $supportMetaPrice = $price_split[0]." ".$price_split[1];

        $supportMetaPrice = ucwords($supportMetaPrice);

        $update_price = "Update ".$prefix."postmeta
                                Set meta_key = '$supportMetaPrice'
                                Where post_id = $supportMetaID
                                And meta_key Like '%product_price%'";
        mysql_query($update_price);
    }
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'customtaxorder_init');
```

Any idea?

Comment: This isn't an appropriate question for SO, if you want someone to urgently debug your code then hire a developer. This has also been asked and answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074477/the-plugin-generated-x-characters-of-unexpected-output

Comment: sorry bro, i am a developer, and i make a wp plugin first time

Comment: Why `mysql_query` if you have **`$wpdb`**?

Comment: Kill the script at the end of customtaxorder_init function to see that unexpected output.

Comment: @Danijel how can i "kill the script" please tell me

Comment: After the plugin's activation hook is run the page is redirected, and if there was some output generated WP will show that error message. Quick workaround is to use die() at the end of activation to see that output in browser, it is probably PHP warning or notice.

Comment: Check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/84284/12615)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using dreamweaver then there is a option "Apply source formatting" under control menu, try that and it will remove unwanted whitespaces.

and also make sure there are no any extra whitespaces or line breaks after the ?>(php closing tag at the end of your page..)

Comment: Thanx bro, from your answer my issue is solved.......thanx alot

Comment: Glad i could be of help.

Comment: Empty lines after the ?> closing tag was my problem. Thanks.

Comment: i have remove white space after closing ?> tags and new it's working fine thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) Please remove extra spacing in the inner pages or plugin pages.

2) remove the inline styling in the pages or plugin pages.

its worked for me everytime. i have used many times same method. when the problem error in the plugin page or Wordpress page.

Regards,

Hitesh Nagpal

Answer (score -2):

Disable error reporting i.e `define('WP_DEBUG', false);`  It worked for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11282539)

Comment: @RaviHirani I have added because it worked for me.

Comment: May be it worked for you. But in this case, It is not a issue. Also I am not a downvoter ;)