# The plugin generated x characters of unexpected output

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm developing WordPress plugin and do get this error on activation:

> Error : The plugin generated 4 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

The snippet below illustrates how my plugin looks like:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: XXXXX
Plugin URI: XXXXX
Description: XXXXX
Version: 1.0
Author: XXXXX
Author URI: XXXXX
License: GNU
*/

echo"test";
?>
```

What is causing this error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: have you give plugin name same as a file name or folder name ?

use following link for create plugin
https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [x characters generated by WordPress plugin during activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074477/x-characters-generated-by-wordpress-plugin-during-activation)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues:

1. Your plugin shouldn't directly `echo` anything. Instead, add your `echo` to a WordPress hook if you need to test things. For example, replace your `echo "test";` with something like:

   ```
   add_action( 'init', function() { echo 'test'; });
   ```
2. It's recommended to remove the closing `?>` tag, to avoid "Headers already sent" notifications.