# Wordpress 239 charactors of unexpected output error

Tags: wordpress, plugins, activation

I am new to wordpress. Here is a task for me.
I need to active a plugin that is created already.
Now, when I try to active it, it gives me following error.

The plugin generated 239 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

So, first thing I did was google. One of the reasong I found was the white-space left behind code somewhere.
So, I followed it and removed blanks from my code. but did not help me out.

Now, I am putting my code herewith this post. Can anyone please help me out. its going really irritating.

```html
<?php
/* 
 * Plugin Name: Lucky Draw
 * Description: Plugin For Lucky Draw Voucher And Spinning
 * Author: Techuz Infoweb Pvt. Ltd
 */
/* Die page if access directly from url */
defined('ABSPATH') or die('No script kiddies please!');
ob_start();
/* Runs when plugin is activated */
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'luckydraw_install');
/* = Use Wordpress functions in plugin files
---------------------------------------------------- */
if (file_exists(ABSPATH.'wp-load.php')) {
    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-load.php');
}
/* = Include Wordpress datatable class
---------------------------------------------------- */
if(!class_exists('WP_List_Table')){
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}
/* = Setup Tables in database
---------------------------------------------------- */
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'ws_setup.php');
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'ws_luckydraw_setup_tables');
/* = Include All the plugin pages in ws_register_pages.php file
---------------------------------------------------- */
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'ws_register_pages.php');
/* = Include scripts and styles
---------------------------------------------------- */
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','ws_luckydraw_load_scripts');
if(!function_exists('ws_luckydraw_load_scripts')) {
        function ws_luckydraw_load_scripts() {
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
            wp_enqueue_media();
            wp_enqueue_style('thickbox'); // call to media files in wp
            wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
            wp_enqueue_script('media-upload'); 
            wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css', plugins_url('lucky-draw/css/jquery-ui.css'));
            wp_enqueue_style('style', plugins_url('lucky-draw/css/ld_style.css'));
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-js', plugins_url('lucky-draw/js/jquery-ui.js'));
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery-datetimepicker-script', plugins_url('lucky-draw/js/jquery.datetimepicker.js'));
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery-validate-js', plugins_url('lucky-draw/js/jquery.validate.js'));
            wp_enqueue_script('common-js', plugins_url('lucky-draw/js/common.js'));
        }
}
/* = Luckydraw Deactivation
---------------------------------------------------- */
if(!function_exists('ws_luckydraw_deactivate')):
    function ws_luckydraw_deactivate() {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
endif;
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'ws_luckydraw_deactivate');
?>
```

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The plugin generated X characters of unexpected output during activation (WordPress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074477/the-plugin-generated-x-characters-of-unexpected-output-during-activation-wordpr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why? no ones gonna answer here. however I found one, it was silly mistake.

register_activation_hook(**FILE**, 'luckydraw_install');

was called twice, and above call was of no use for me. So I have removed above call, and error has gone.