# Plugin generated XXX of unexpected output during activation

Tags: wordpress

The plugin generated 79 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

Code As Bellow

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:Stock Notifier
Plugin URI:
Description: product out of stock.
Version: 1
*/

include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
if ( is_plugin_active( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php' ) || class_exists( 'WooCommerce' )) {


class Stock_Notifier {

} // End Class GIS_Stock_Notifier

new Stock_Notifier();

}else { ?> 
<!-- When remove else then work perfect but i need display notice message -->
<div class="update-nag notice">
    <p>First Install Woocoomerce Plugin</p>
</div>  
<?php
}
```

Plugin depend to woocommerce plugin. 
When in else part **Remove** Start PHP and End PHP then **work** but How to print message of notice.

Suggest me.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [x characters generated by WordPress plugin during activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074477/x-characters-generated-by-wordpress-plugin-during-activation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plugin shouldn't output or echo anything by itself, and should instead use [hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#WordPress_Plugin_Hooks) to manipulate content.

If you do so, and still have the error

> Plugin generated X lines of unexpected output during activation

you can install [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-plugin-activation-errors/) to see what was the output of the plugin.