# Wordpress Plugin Activited Header Already Send Error

Tags: wordpress, header

I'm about to go crazy :/

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: TEST Plugin
Description: test desc
Author: test
Author URI: test
Plugin URI: test
*/
echo"test";
?>
```

> Error : The plugin generated 4 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems
>   with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing
>   this plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The plugin generated X characters of unexpected output during activation (WordPress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074477/the-plugin-generated-x-characters-of-unexpected-output-during-activation-wordpr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove unnecessary white space or line break
that will remove the error
also remove last

```
?>
```

Try bellow code

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: TEST Plugin
    Description: test desc
    Author: test
    Author URI: test
    Plugin URI: test
*/
ob_start();
echo 'test';
ob_clean();
```

Comment: No unnecessary space :/

Comment: Your edits do not solve the problem.  Further, you didn't explain what they do.

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin cannot simply `echo "test"` in the file.  **That is** what is generating the unexpected output.

Remove that.

All output that a plugin generates should be inside of functions, which typically get called by using one of the many [WordPress Hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks).

Here's a super-simple, (and useless) example:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: TEST Plugin
Description: test desc
Author: test
Author URI: test
Plugin URI: test
*/

// Hooks into the WordPress wp_head action
add_action('wp_head', 'my_wp_head_function');

// Runs when the WordPress init action runs
function my_wp_head_function() {
    echo "test";
}

// ... etc

// Also - DO omit the closing PHP tag.  That is now considered best practice
```

Comment: @FerdiKUCUK - using `ob_start` and `ob_end` is **not a good solution**.  You need to learn how to use the WP hooks.