# The plugin generated 515 characters of unexpected output during activation

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: SQL table creator
Author: Md. Sarwar-A-Kawsar
Author URI: https://xyz.abc
*/

defined('ABSPATH') or die('You cannot access to this page');
function stb_sql_custom_activate(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'eg_all_videos';
    if( $wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE ".$table_name) != $table_name ){
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
          id INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          old_id INT(5) DEFAULT NULL,
          type VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
          title VARCHAR(300) DEFAULT NULL,
          year year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
          segment_number INT(3) DEFAULT NULL,
          slug VARCHAR(300) DEFAULT NULL,
          UNIQUE KEY (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'stb_sql_custom_activate' );
```

I've used the above code in my plugin but getting this error during activate the plugin:

```
The plugin generated 515 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers
already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing 
this plugin.
```

I've changed the SQL query but didn't get any luck and would appreciate if anyone helps to solve this issue.

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The plugin generated X characters of unexpected output during activation (WordPress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074477/the-plugin-generated-x-characters-of-unexpected-output-during-activation-wordpr)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
```

It is creating output before headers are sent. I'm also not sure why that is there at all.

Comment: Now getting this error - `WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'wp_eg_all_videos' at line 1]
SHOW TABLES LIKE wp_eg_all_videos`

Comment: "SHOW TABLES LIKE  '{$table_name]'"

Comment: It working fine in another wordpress installation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usage `ob_start();` - turn output buffering on, and `return ob_get_clean();` -  return & clean buffer contents help for me.

```
<?php 

/**
* Plugin Name: Custom Testimonials Slider
* Description: This plugin for "What My Clients Say" section
* Version: 2.0.0
**/

/**
 * Shortcode plugin
 */
 add_shortcode("testimonials-slider", "testimonials_slider_activation");

/**
 * Activation plugin
 */
 register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'testimonials_slider_activation' );
 function testimonials_slider_activation() {

    ob_start();

    //your code is here

    return ob_get_clean();

}

?>
```