# The plugin generated 33545 characters of unexpected output during activation

Tags: wordpress, plugins

The plugin generated 33545 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

Does anyone know how to fix this without disabling debug true in the wp-config.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The plugin generated X characters of unexpected output during activation (WordPress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074477/the-plugin-generated-x-characters-of-unexpected-output-during-activation-wordpr)

Comment: After Deactivating my own custom plugin. And tried to deactivate some WordPress-verified plugins and activate them again the errors keep showing in every plugin.